# How can I have a thread tell the method that started it when it has completed doing its setup?

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify

I have a method that starts a thread, and I want to have the method block until the thread finishes its setup stage, or else face a race condition.

I know I want to use wait notify, but I don't know how to own the monitor and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move your "setup stage" out of `run()` and into an `init()` method.

```
MyRunnableClass mrc = new MyRunnableClass();
mrc.init();
Thread t = new Thread(mrc);
t.start();
```

**Edit:** Or as @Buhb noted in the comments below, just put it in the constructor. Years of C++ makes old habits die hard.

Comment: or even put the initialization in the constructor.

Comment: @Buhb - You know ... my c++ is showing. That's actually fine in Java, I always forget you can't end up with memory leaks in Java doing that.

Answer (score 5):

I generally use a [Count down latch](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) if only the starting thread needs to wait.

There are examples there but I can throw up a quicky example if you need it.

Or you could use a [barrier](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) if multiple threads are likely to use thread and need to know when it is initialized.

Comment: Specifically, a CountDownLatch with the count set to 1. The parent thread calls start() on the child thread and then await() on the latch, while the child thread simply calls countDown() after finishing initialization. This is also pretty easy to do with raw wait/notify, but the CountDownLatch makes the intent clear in the code, and is free of bugs that you might introduce if you wrote it yourself.

Comment: I've actually been doing this with wait/notify, but I'll put this to good use in the future.